# Using a sphere collider in combination with FoV

Tags: unity

I have a character and some npc's in my game. I want the npc's to look out for my character using a sphere collider. Well it kind of works but of course not as i want. When the npc is looking at me and a colission occurs it should trigger some chasing behaviour, but if the npc look in another direction, it should not trigger that behaviour.

So i need something like a field of view inside the collider. I watched some tutorials like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rQG9aUWarwE and  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mBGUY7EUxXQ but it should be 3 dimensional so not only on the ground like in the tutorial. I added a picture to visualize it [image]

How can i accomplish this?

Comment: Have you reviewed [past questions about implementing vision cone detection within a spherical area in Unity](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/118675/39518)? Did you run into any specific trouble implementing the answers you've found so far?

Comment: My problem is the height especially. When the player stands on a wall or cube above the AI he wont see him.

Comment: Have you looked at using a frustum for detecting? Something like this. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB.html

Comment: @DMGregory there are 2 answers - one using Vector3.Dot, the other one using Vector3.Angle. None of them using both and both are not applied to all axes. I just dont understand it, can you explain it a little bit more?

Comment: Yes, there are two answers, one using Dot and one using Angle. None of the answers exclude the Y axis. Every answer there can serve your case, so it's not at all clear to me where you're having trouble. Can you please explain what you've tried and where you're stuck?

Comment: allright, thank you. never mind.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [the approaches using Vector3.Dot or .Angle to check whether the line from the observer to the target fits within a round cone](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/118675/39518), we could also try an approach like this to get a pyramidal field of view, that can be wider horizontally than vertically for example:

```
[Tooltip("Horizontal & vertical field of view of the agent's vision pyramid, in degrees, measured from the central axis")]
public Vector2 fieldOfView = new Vector2(45, 30);

[Tooltip("Assign a transform here to represent the position of the observer's eyes")]
public Transform eye;

void OnTriggerStay(Collider collider) {
    // Transform the target's (pivot) position into the eye's frame of reference.
    Vector3 inEyeSpace = eye.InverseTransformPoint(collider.transform.position);

    // Dividing by depth gives us the slope of the ray to the target...
    Vector2 tangent = ((Vector2)inEyeSpace) / inEyeSpace.z;

    // ...which we can compare against the limits of our FoV angles.
    Vector2 radians = fieldOfView * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
    bool inHorizontalRange = Mathf.Abs(tangent.x) <= Mathf.Tan(radians.x);
    bool inVerticalRange = Mathf.Abs(tangent.y) <= Mathf.Tan(radians.y);

    // If the target is in front of the eye and not out of range on either axis, we see it!
    if(inEyeSpace.z > 0 && inHorizontalRange && inVerticalRange)
         Detect(collider.gameObject); // Trigger your detection, or confirm with a raycast first.
}
```

By placing a (potentially empty) GameObject where the character's head should be, and assigning its Transform to the `eye` variable, you can control both where the vision pyramid originates, and also its direction - for instance if you wanted to angle it downward so the character sees more of what's below them than above them.

You can add a gizmo method to help visualize the shape of the vision pyramid in the scene view and double-check that detection is occurring as you expect. The far corners aren't quite exact - I'm neglecting here the curvature or center of the sphere collider - but it provides a decent visual aid all the same.

```
void OnDrawGizmos() {
    var sphere = GetComponent<SphereCollider>();
    if(sphere == null || eye == null)
        return;

    Vector2 radians = fieldOfView * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
    Vector3 localCorner = new Vector3(
                                 Mathf.Tan(radians.x),
                                 Mathf.Tan(radians.y),
                                 1
                          ) * sphere.radius;

    Vector3 topRight = eye.TransformPoint(localCorner);
    localCorner.x *= -1f;
    Vector3 topLeft = eye.TransformPoint(localCorner);
    localCorner.y *= -1f;
    Vector3 bottomLeft = eye.TransformPoint(localCorner);
    localCorner.x *= -1f;
    Vector3 bottomRight = eye.TransformPoint(localCorner);

    Gizmos.DrawLine(eye.position, topLeft);
    Gizmos.DrawLine(eye.position, topRight);
    Gizmos.DrawLine(eye.position, bottomLeft);
    Gizmos.DrawLine(eye.position, bottomRight);
    Gizmos.DrawLine(topLeft, topRight);
    Gizmos.DrawLine(topRight, bottomRight);
    Gizmos.DrawLine(bottomRight, bottomLeft);
    Gizmos.DrawLine(bottomLeft, topLeft);
}
```

Comment: As you may have noticed (because you answered my other question https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/171778/ignore-physics-material-on-raycast-shooting) i am using a different approach now so the problem of height is solved for me. Anyways, this answer is very informative to me, thanks